# Cannot access localhost:8080 from browser

Tags: python

I am running this simple command in my terminal:

```
python -m http.server 8080
```

But when I try to access localhost:8080, nothing came out. Why does this happen? Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

When I tried another python code provided by the Udacity course:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# 
# A buggy web service in need of a database.

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

from forumdb import get_posts, add_post

app = Flask(__name__)

# HTML template for the forum page
HTML_WRAP = '''\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Forum</title>
    <style>
      h1, form { text-align: center; }
      textarea { width: 400px; height: 100px; }
      div.post { border: 1px solid #999;
                 padding: 10px 10px;
                 margin: 10px 20%%; }
      hr.postbound { width: 50%%; }
      em.date { color: #999 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>DB Forum</h1>
    <form method=post>
      <div><textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea></div>
      <div><button id="go" type="submit">Post message</button></div>
    </form>
    <!-- post content will go here -->
%s
  </body>
</html>
'''

# HTML template for an individual comment
POST = '''\
    <div class=post><em class=date>%s</em><br>%s</div>
'''


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
  '''Main page of the forum.'''
  posts = "".join(POST % (date, text) for text, date in get_posts())
  html = HTML_WRAP % posts
  return html


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def post():
  '''New post submission.'''
  message = request.form['content']
  add_post(message)
  return redirect(url_for('main'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

when I tried this for the first time, it worked just fine. But then I closed the terminal. The second time I try to run this python file, I couldn't connect to localhost:8000 anymore.

the same problem keeps coming back.
Sometimes it works fine and I see the page I want. Why is that?

Question:
Do I run the webserver from my virtualMachine or from my macos system?

Comment: Why do you think 8080 should respond?  That isn't HTTP or HTTPS.  The only thing I know might use that port by default is Jenkins.

Comment: I don't really understand,but this class in Udacity says that the server is supposed to respond? I saw this in mt terminal :```Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...```but the server doesn't recieve any kind of request.

Comment: @FrankMerrow errr... what? http is not wedded to port 80; it's just the default

Comment: so..?how can I fix it? It has been bothering me for a few hours and all the google results didn't work.

Comment: Did you try http://127.0.0.1:8080 ?

Comment: More info: I tried 127.0.0.1:8080 didn't work.. I left the shell/terminal open. No,I don't think any other application is listening on 8080. I see the same google search page when I try to visit the page. I am using chrome. Curling didn't work :(

Comment: @Rachel_Miller if you are using python 2.7 try running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Comment: my terminal says ```/Users/IMAC/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named SimpleHTTPServer```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create a python file (server.py) in your project file.

Copy the code below into server.py

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT  = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("",PORT), Handler)
print("Server at PORT : ",PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

After that, run the following code command=>

`python server.py`

Comment: But umm, can you tell me what's wrong with my python code?

Comment: @Rachel_Miller The original error comes from the fact that the [self.wfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.wfile) attribute of your server is a [BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) object that requires bytes input. You can fix this with: `output = b"<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that self.wfile attribute is a BufferedIOBase object. I did as you told and changed my code, now it can totally work. Thanks!!!

Comment: Note: This is not secure. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html @Rachel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe nothing comes out because it's an empty server? You have no HTML content.

You can do this

```
mkdir /tmp/www
echo 'It works' > /tmp/www/index.html
python -m http.server 8080 --directory /tmp/www
```

And in a new terminal

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080
```

You should see something

Comment: In general , use a web framework https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks/

Comment: oh umm.. the problem I had earlier is actually fixed. But I am totally interested in using web frameworks. Just a quick question, it is beginnner friendly?

Comment: Frameworks are designed to be more friendly than the standard API, yes. Flask is a popular one to get started, and many companies use it in production

Comment: cool, thanks! I am just strating to learn about web programming. I will check it out.